# UIButton won't open new view Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am having trouble getting a new view controller to show on the screen when the button is pressed. I created a subclass of `UIViewController` named `StartUpVC`. I added it to the app delegate.m and created an instance of `StartupVC *startUpVC = [StartUpVC new]` and then set `self.window.rootViewController = startUpVC;`. So now in the `StartUpVC` class, I created a button so a user can log in with a `UIImageView`in the background. Now when the button is pressed, it doesn't open up the view controller for the log in screen and does nothing. So my question is how do i get it to open that view controller? Or should it simply be a `UIView` that opens when the button is pressed?

This is in the StartUpVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 ...Code Irrelevant to the question here...

//Create Log In Button
    UIButton *logInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    logInButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 480, 280, 40);
    logInButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    logInButton.layer.opacity = .6;
    logInButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [logInButton setTitle:@"Log In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [logInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendToLogInScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];

}

-(void)sendToLogInScreen:(id)sender {

    LogInVC *logIn = [LogInVC new];

    [self presentViewController:logIn animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: is your sentToLogInScreen: method getting called when you press the button?

Comment: And are you using storyboards?

Comment: No storyboards, all UI is being done in code.

Comment: Reconsider the decision to not use storyboards.  They'll make your life much easier (in this case, just ctrl-drag from your button to your LogInViewController)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to know is whether the method `sendToLogInScreen` is getting called at all. Place a breakpoint anywhere in the function to check.

Once you know whether the function is getting called at the proper time or not, this problem will either be about:

- `sendToLogInScreen` is not getting called

  - Something is wrong with the button

    - it's nil
    - the gesture isn't setup properly
  - UserInteraction is disabled for `StartupVC`'s `view` property
- `sendToLogInScreen` is getting called

  - `logIn` is nil
  - `presentViewController` is failing for some reason

Hope that helps you figure out what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ill try to see where it is going wrong with one of the methods.